# I am trying to extract a block of lines from a file

Tags: regex, multiline

```
import re
def regex_func(string):
    pattern=re.compile(r"""(?mx)
    ^DISPLAY MANAGER\s*.*\s*
    \s*mOnlyCode=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mSafeMode=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mPendingTraversal=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mGlobalDisplayState=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mNextNonDefaultDisplayId=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mViewports=\s*(.*) deviceWidth=([\d]+), deviceHeight=([\d]+)\}\]$""")
    result = pattern.findall(string)
    if result:
        print(result)

def main():
   logfile = open("dumpstate.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')        
   regex_func(logfile.read())
   logfile.close()
```

Input snippet:

```
DUMP OF SERVICE display:
DISPLAY MANAGER (dumpsys display)
  mOnlyCode=false
  mSafeMode=false
  mPendingTraversal=false
  mGlobalDisplayState=ON
  mNextNonDefaultDisplayId=2
  mViewports=[DisplayViewport{type=INTERNAL, valid=true, displayId=0, uniqueId='local:0', physicalPort=0, orientation=0, logicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), physicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), deviceWidth=1080, deviceHeight=2340}]
  mDefaultDisplayDefaultColorMode=0
  mSingleDisplayDemoMode=false
  mWifiDisplayScanRequestCount=0
  mStableDisplaySize=Point(1080, 2340)
  mMinimumBrightnessCurve=[(0.0, 0.0), (2000.0, 50.0), (4000.0, 90.0)]
```

Problem:
I am trying to extract a block of lines starting from "DISPLAY MANAGER" till the line that contains "mViewports=". I reused a multiline pattern that works (in another case). (I am new to regex).
The pattern is returning no match. Requesting help from expert members.

Comment: If you only need things until deviceHeight than this could be it maybe https://regex101.com/r/U26kmH/1

Comment: appreciate your kind help. it does work on the (regex101) portal, but not in my script.py file. I have no clue what's wrong. My input is an entire file read() once.

Comment: Yes I tried your code and neither work for me. Unfortunately I am noob with python so don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Completely Revised Answer**

I added the `re.DEBUG` flag to see what what the regex engine was actually scanning for. In part:

```
CHARACTER MATCH 'D'
CHARACTER MATCH 'I'
CHARACTER MATCH 'S'
CHARACTER MATCH 'P'
CHARACTER MATCH 'L'
CHARACTER MATCH 'A'
CHARACTER MATCH 'Y'
CHARACTER MATCH 'M'
CHARACTER MATCH 'A'
CHARACTER MATCH 'N'
CHARACTER MATCH 'A'
CHARACTER MATCH 'G'
CHARACTER MATCH 'E'
CHARACTER MATCH 'R'
```

So, in `VERBOSE` mode it was ignoring the space character between `DISPLAY` and `MANAGER` (and elsewhere). From the Python manual:

**re.VERBOSE**

> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer and are more readable by allowing you to visually separate logical sections of the pattern and add comments. **Whitespace within the pattern is ignored**, except when in a character class, or when preceded by an unescaped backslash, or within tokens like *?, (?: or (?P<...>. When a line contains a # that is not in a character class and is not preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such # through the end of the line are ignored.

I then replaced each occurrence of space with `\x20` and it worked:

```
import re
def regex_func(string):
    pattern=re.compile(r"""(?mx)
    ^DISPLAY\x20MANAGER\s*.*\s*
    \s*mOnlyCode=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mSafeMode=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mPendingTraversal=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mGlobalDisplayState=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mNextNonDefaultDisplayId=\s*.*\s*
    \s*mViewports=\s*(.*)\x20deviceWidth=([\d]+),\x20deviceHeight=([\d]+)\}\]$""")
    result = pattern.findall(string)
    if result:
        print(result)

text = """DUMP OF SERVICE display:
DISPLAY MANAGER (dumpsys display)
  mOnlyCode=false
  mSafeMode=false
  mPendingTraversal=false
  mGlobalDisplayState=ON
  mNextNonDefaultDisplayId=2
  mViewports=[DisplayViewport{type=INTERNAL, valid=true, displayId=0, uniqueId='local:0', physicalPort=0, orientation=0, logicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), physicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), deviceWidth=1080, deviceHeight=2340}]
  mDefaultDisplayDefaultColorMode=0
  mSingleDisplayDemoMode=false
  mWifiDisplayScanRequestCount=0
  mStableDisplaySize=Point(1080, 2340)
  mMinimumBrightnessCurve=[(0.0, 0.0), (2000.0, 50.0), (4000.0, 90.0)]"""

regex_func(text)
```

Prints:

```
[("[DisplayViewport{type=INTERNAL, valid=true, displayId=0, uniqueId='local:0', physicalPort=0, orientation=0, logicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), physicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340),", '1080', '2340')]
```